# How to loop through mapply in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, concatenation, mapply, stringi

I am trying to concatenate strings using `mapply` function in R. However, I want one of  the strings to be variable in `mapply` function. I have a snippet of my code below:

```
strings<-data.frame(x=c("dsf","sdf","sdf"))
strings2<-data.frame(extension=c(".csv",".json",".xml"))

for (i in 1:3)
{
  strings_concat<-mapply(function(string1,string2) paste0(string1,string2),strings$x,strings2$extension[i])%>%
    data.frame()%>%
    unlist()%>%
    data.frame()

 #dosomething with strings_concat
}
```

But this is giving me the last iteration only

```
strings_concat

dsf.xml
sdf.xml
sdf.xml
```

bust instead, the desired output is as follows:

```
strings_concat

dsf.csv 
sdf.csv 
sdf.csv 

dsf.json 
sdf.json 
sdf.json 

dsf.xml
sdf.xml
sdf.xml
```

At every iteration, i want to combine `strings_concat` with another dataframe and save it. Can anyone help me if there is an easy way to do this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, `outer` is a better option here :

```
strings_concat <- c(outer(strings$x, strings2$extension, paste0))
strings_concat
#[1] "dsf.csv"  "sdf.csv"  "sdf.csv"  "dsf.json" "sdf.json" "sdf.json" 
#    "dsf.xml"  "sdf.xml"  "sdf.xml"
```

You can add it in a data.frame :

```
df <- data.frame(strings_concat)
```

---

If you want to add some additional steps at each iteration you can use `lapply` :

```
lapply(strings2$extension, function(x) {
  strings_concat <- paste0(strings$x, x)
  #do something with strings_concat
})
```

Comment: this is a great way to solve this but i want to do something with strings_concat at each iteration, is there anyway i can manage that? for instance, in the first iteration, cbind(anotherdataframe,strings_concat), and do something with this combined data frame. do same thing for the rest of iteration

Comment: In that case, I think you can use `lapply`. See updated answer if that helps.

Comment: Yes that is perfect Rokan, but the output I am getting as follows: [[1]]
[1] "dsf.csv"  "dsf.json" "dsf.xml" 

[[2]]
[1] "sdf.csv"  "sdf.json" "sdf.xml" 

[[3]]
[1] "sdf.csv"  "sdf.json" "sdf.xml"

Comment: Yes that is perfect Rokan, but the output I am getting as follows: [[1]]
[1] "dsf.csv"  "dsf.json" "dsf.xml" 
 Instead, I want csv to be in one group, json to be in one group nad xml to be in one group so that i can iterate through them and combine them with another df. for instance, if i save the function results as lists, then lists[[1]]= [[1]]
[1] "dsf.csv"  "sdf.csv"  "sdf.csv"

Comment: You can iterate over `strings2$extension` instead in `lapply`. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

All you should need to do is make sure you are continually augmenting your dataset. So I think this should do the trick:

```
strings<-data.frame(x=c("dsf","sdf","sdf"))
strings2<-data.frame(extension=c(".csv",".json",".xml"))

# We are going to keep adding things to results
results = NULL

for (i in 1:3)
{
  strings_concat<-mapply(function(string1,string2) paste0(string1,string2),strings$x,strings2$extension[i])%>%
    data.frame()%>%
    unlist()%>%
    data.frame()
 # Here is where we keep adding things to results
 results = rbind(results, strings_concat)
}

print(results)
```

**Caution:** not in front a computer with R so this code is untested